# Firstore create multiple documents at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have given an array of document **id's** which I want to add to Firestore.

```
let documentIds = [
  'San Francisco',
  'New York',
  'Las Vegas'
]
```

Each document should have a predefined set of properties.

```
let data = {
  country: 'US',
  language: 'English'
}
```

Is there some function inside the Firebase Admin SDK that can create all documents at once, without iterating through the array of documentIds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help.  Sam's answer will give you a good understanding of how to use batch writes.  Be sure to check out the documentation that he linked to.

*I don't want to upset Sam.  He fixed my laptop, yesterday* :-)

### Setting a batch with an array

```
let documentIds = [
  'San Francisco',
  'New York',
  'Las Vegas'
]

let data = {country: 'US', language: 'English'}

var batch = db.batch();
documentIds.forEach(docId => {
  batch.set(db.doc(`cities/${docId}`), data);
})

batch.commit().then(response => {
  console.log('Success');
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a batched write.  You'll still need to iterate through the docs to add them all to the batch object, but it will be a single network call:

Example:

```
// Get a new write batch
var batch = db.batch();

// Set the value of 'NYC'
var nycRef = db.collection("cities").doc("NYC");
batch.set(nycRef, {name: "New York City"});

// Update the population of 'SF'
var sfRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
batch.update(sfRef, {"population": 1000000});

// Delete the city 'LA'
var laRef = db.collection("cities").doc("LA");
batch.delete(laRef);

// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes